# Sending type into c++ class

Tags: c++

In vector we have:

```
vector<type> name;
```

How can I create this "`<type>`" for my own class to passing the type?

Comment: What exactly are you asking here?  How to use `vector`?  Or how to write your own version?

Comment: Or are you asking how to use templates with your own class?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_%28C++%29).

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
class myClass
{
public:    
    myClass(T value){std::cout << value;}
};

int main()
{
    myClass<int> c(1);
}
```

Comment: @RafałWądołowski Be careful with what types you pass in though. Here, the constructor works because `cout << (int)` is defined. If you were to pass in `AnotherClass` you would have to ensure that you overload AnotherClass's `<<` operator (or any others you wish to use).

Comment: @PLPiper That is true, this example would defiantly not be a prefect case for a template. But it is designed to be a short example. That is why I linked to the Wikipedia page encase he wanted more in depth.

Comment: I have to write alone vector class.

Answer (score 0):

create a class `template`.

e.g.

```
template< class item_t >
class my_vector_t
{
    // whatever
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are asking what to put in place of `type` when using a vector. This is simply the name of your class:

```
vector<MyClass> myVec;
```